# Remove particular items from XML

Tags: regex, xml, linux, shell, parsing

I have an XML feed with my e-commerce products for Google Shopping. I need to modify this XML and remove items with a particular category. What would be the quickest way to do this?

Condition is: if `g:google_product_category` is 5613 then remove whole `<item>`

[image]

The best way would be to use just some kind of regex and terminal to avoid importing/parsing/exporting libraries.

EDIT:

I tried to use `<item>(.+?)<g:google_product_category><!\[CDATA\[5613\]\]><\/g:google_product_category>[\W]+</item>` regular expression and replace it with empty string but seems that it's not finding any items.

Comment: Please, post testable sample data with related expected output, edit them to the original post as text. lso, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest to use XSLT transformation. XSLT is made for what you need.